# AngularJS: Place holder not showing

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

My code should display two img elements simultaneously. The scope from the two img is defined in the controller but only one of the imgs is being displayed in the default the context. Below is my complete source code:

**Controller.js**

```js
.controller("ExampleController", function($scope, $cordovaCamera) {

    $scope.takePicture = function() {
        var options = { 
            quality : 75, 
            destinationType : Camera.DestinationType.DATA_URL, 
            sourceType : Camera.PictureSourceType.CAMERA, 
            allowEdit : false,
            encodingType: Camera.EncodingType.JPEG,
            targetWidth: 350,
            targetHeight: 350,
            popoverOptions: CameraPopoverOptions,
            correctOrientation: true,
            saveToPhotoAlbum: false
        };

        $cordovaCamera.getPicture(options).then(function(imageData) {
            $scope.imgURI = "data:image/jpeg;base64," + imageData;
        }, function(err) {
            // An error occured. Show a message to the user
        });
    };

    //beginning of select from gallery scope

    $scope.ImageURI = 'Select Image';
    function UploadPicture(imageURI) {

        $scope.ImageURI =  imageURI;
        $scope.$apply(); 
        alert($scope.ImageURI );
    }

    $scope.ShowPictures = function() {
        navigator.camera.getPicture(UploadPicture, function(message) {
                alert('get picture aborted!');
            }, {
                quality: 75,
                destinationType: navigator.camera.DestinationType.FILE_URI,
                sourceType: navigator.camera.PictureSourceType.PHOTOLIBRARY,
                targetWidth: 200,
                correctOrientation: true,
                allowEdit : false,
                encodingType: Camera.EncodingType.JPEG,
                targetHeight: 200
            }
        );
    };

})
```

**index.html**

```html
<div class="item item-image">
    <img ng-show="ImageURI !== undefined" ng-src="{{ImageURI}}" style="max-width: 40%">
    <img ng-show="ImageURI === undefined" ng-src="http://placehold.it/300x300" style="max-width: 100%">
</div>

<div class="item item-image">
    <img ng-show="imgURI !== undefined" ng-src="{{imgURI}}" style="max-width: 40%">
    <img ng-show="imgURI === undefined" ng-src="http://placehold.it/300x300" style="max-width: 100%">
</div>
```

This line isn't displayed in the view

```
<img ng-show="ImageURI === undefined" ng-src="http://placehold.it/300x300" style="max-width: 100%">
```

Comment: http://placehold.it/300x300 this image not display when nothing is selected right?

Comment: Do you receive this alert ? ('get picture aborted!')

Comment: Yes! I receive the alert

Comment: Yes. It does not display when nothing is selected. @ Paresh

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Controller

```
.controller("ExampleController", function($scope, $cordovaCamera) 
{   
    //=======================TAKE PIC-===========================//

    $scope.imgURI = "http://placehold.it/300x300";

    $scope.takePicture = function() 
    {
        var options = { 
            quality : 75, 
            destinationType : Camera.DestinationType.DATA_URL, 
            sourceType : Camera.PictureSourceType.CAMERA, 
            allowEdit : false,
            encodingType: Camera.EncodingType.JPEG,
            targetWidth: 350,
            targetHeight: 350,
            popoverOptions: CameraPopoverOptions,
            correctOrientation: true,
            saveToPhotoAlbum: false
        };

        $cordovaCamera.getPicture(options).then(function(imageData) {
            $scope.imgURI = "data:image/jpeg;base64," + imageData;
        }, function(err) {
            // An error occured. Show a message to the user
        });
    };

    //=============================CAMERA===============================//

    $scope.ImageURI = "http://placehold.it/300x300";

    function UploadPicture(imageURI) 
    {
        $scope.ImageURI =  imageURI;
        $scope.$apply(); 
        alert($scope.ImageURI );
    }

    $scope.ShowPictures = function() 
    {
        navigator.camera.getPicture(UploadPicture, function(message) 
        {
                alert('get picture aborted!');
            }, {
                quality: 75,
                destinationType: navigator.camera.DestinationType.FILE_URI,
                sourceType: navigator.camera.PictureSourceType.PHOTOLIBRARY,
                targetWidth: 200,
                correctOrientation: true,
                allowEdit : false,
                encodingType: Camera.EncodingType.JPEG,
                targetHeight: 200
            }
        );
    };
})
```

### Html

```
<div class="item item-image">
    <img ng-src="{{ImageURI}}" style="max-width: 40%">
</div>

<div class="item item-image">
    <img ng-src="{{imgURI}}" style="max-width: 40%">
</div>
```

Comment: Is there a way I can manipulate it in the view instead of in the controller. Thanks

Comment: Please can you edit your answer. I dont get what you mean in this "and in html do like this"

Comment: I add whole controller and html in answer please check

Comment: Thanks. Is there a way I can use a button to hide and show a pop up either takePicture or showPicture button in angularjs

Comment: i cannot get you what you say

Comment: I want to use a button to trigger a choice on either takePicture or showPicture. For example if I click a button eg "upload" if I select takePicture button on the pop up, it hides showPicture {{imgUri}} and displays {{imageURI}}. Instead of displaying the two view simultanously

Comment: I want one image view to be the default, then if you click any of the button  "takepicture" or "showpicture" let it replace the current image view

Comment: Yes you can when you open popup and take choice from user at that time take one variable and based on that you can hide show button and here you have use only image tag for view

Comment: Please can you help me?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/90416/discussion-between-paresh-gami-and-jng).